# Can MS Excel use non-printable characters as field separators in CSV files? If so, how?

Tags: excel, csv

I've just discovered that many of the character encodings have [non-printable characters designed to separate different pieces of information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter#ASCII_delimited_text), e.g., ASCII character 31 is the "unit separator".  It seems that if I could use one of these characters as the separator in a "comma/character separated value" (CSV), I could avoid problems in escaping the values that could occur in text, e.g., commas.

Is it possible to make MS Excel use the "unit separator" instead of a comma?  If so, how can I do that?

**EDIT**: I've re-entered [this question in SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/733462/can-ms-excel-use-non-printable-characters-as-field-separators-in-csv-files-if-s), where it's been answered.

Comment: How can I migrate this to Super User, now that I've created an account there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the list separator for a "CSV" system-wide by going into Control Panel, Region and Language, Formats, Advanced (on Windows 7), and change the list separator.  I changed it to a backtick and then saved a spreadsheet as a CSV, and it used a backtick as the delimiter.  You can try pasting the ASCII character in from the character map or using the Alt+# code.

(If you're trying to open a file, the Import Wizard should let you set the delimiter that's being used in the file).

It may be simpler to save as a tab-separated document, unless tabs are appearing in your text.

[image: Screenshot of dialog box referenced]